# Woocommerce with Wordpress - Change text for creating password on checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On Woocommerce with Wordpress, I'm having difficulties changing the text above account password when someone is on the checkout page.

Please see below screenshot, it's highlighted in red box.

[image: attachment]

I believe one way can be through the .php files on the server for the website, however I've tried my-account.php and checkout-form.php in the files of the website, and I can't see the text to rename this part.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, it's best to use the in-built hooks and actions to change things, otherwise if the core template changes in the plugin, your copy in your theme template becomes out-of-date.

The paragraph of text you highlighted it is in the template, so to change the text you would need to change the template, but another option is to simply hide it with CSS, then change the 'Account Password' label below it to say what you want.

Drop this into your functions.php file to change that label without needing the theme template override:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['account']['account_password']['label'] = 'Your new message here';
    return $fields;
}
```

You can also use that same function to change other labels if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to my child theme's functions.php to change "returning customer" to "returning student":

```
//Change the Create Account checkout text
function wc_create_account_field_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
switch ( $translated_text ) {
case 'Create an account by entering the information below. If you are a returning customer please login at the top of the page.' :
$translated_text = __( 'Create an account by entering the information below. If you are a returning student please login at the top of the page.', 'woocommerce' );
break;
}
return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wc_create_account_field_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: It's far better to make changes like this than to modify templates.

Answer (score 0):

This text is located in your theme folder, approximately: `woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-billing.php` ~ line:53.

Look for:

```
<p><?php _e( 'Create an account by entering the information below. If you are a returning customer please login at the top of the page.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

Also look at https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/ for any changes to the actual form elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That didn't work for me - but when trying through themes/mytheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php it worked.

Thanks

Comment: Right - you're using the woocommerce template override. It's the same thing. I'll modify my answer to include 'check your theme'. This answer should be acceptable for you.

Answer (score 0):

find template-hook and  template-tags folder in your project.
I found at wp-content/themes/theme_name/inc/woocommerce.

And the message are consist on files in template-tags folder but you must first know hook name first.